# How to secure a static route with Express and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use Node (latest version) + Express, also latest Version. I have 2 folders, public and secured. The secured folder should only be accessible after login.

I've create a login system by myself, now I wonder how I can secure the route to this "secure-folder".

I was thining about setting a static route to my "secured" folder (like I did with the public one) and then check whether the user is logged in, but it doesn't work.

This is what I thought should work...

```
(...)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'secured')));
(...)

function requireLogin(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.loggedIn) {
    next(); // allow the next route to run
  } else {
    // require the user to log in
    res.redirect("/login"); 
  }
}

app.all("/secured/*", requireLogin, function(req, res, next) {
  next(); 

});
```

Comment: did u have the secured folder in the public one??

Comment: For anyone reading this question now (after Feb 2019), please note that this can easily be accomplished with  middleware.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Specify a different folder for your private statics on a separate route

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/private', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'private')));
```

Then you can use your middleware on each request

```
app.all('/private/*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.loggedIn) {
    next(); // allow the next route to run
  } else {
    // require the user to log in
    res.redirect("/login"); 
  }
})
```

Comment: mhm. both of the solutions doesn't work... If I try Pascal's code, I'll get an exception that says that req.session is undefined.

If I try zeMicro's solution, I am able to get access to the secured folder, but node then says: "Can't get /secured/index.html".

By the way, what is the difference between this:
     app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'secured')));
and that:
     app.use('/secured',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'secured')));

Comment: it seems like app.all('/private/*') just matches for the private folder, but if the user types in /private/index.html, it doesn't match this rule..

Comment: Ok, I got it to work now.

The trick is to put the app.all(/private/*).. before you define the static route to your private folder.

Sorry, I am new to node, but I learned a lot today. Thank you!

Comment: `app.all` is part of the `router`. As you said in your last comment put the `router` above the `static` middleware.

Answer (score 6):

before your first app.use,

add something like

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.match(/^\/secured\//)) {
    return requireLogin(req, res, next);
  }
  next();
})
```