# Node.js Express.js secret static files

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm building a **single page** admin panel for my website in node express.

I've decided to have one admin view file and to load parts of html into it via jQuery or AJAX or something similar (did not decide yet).

I have to serve these files from static files folder (because i have to load them client side), but problem here is that these files are now avaible for everyone (also .css .js files etc...).

**Any possibility how to hide these files from users? Or how to hide certain files or load files on client side which are not public?**

And i really dont want to insert all my .css and .js code inside my admin view file.

## **SOLUTION**

Found a solution here : [How to secure a static route with Express and Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612774/how-to-secure-a-static-route-with-express-and-nodejs)

Sorry for duplicate, i did not find it before.

Comment: Seems like you need to use some kind of authorization to handle which files should be served to those who are allowed to view it. Take a look at [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-authorization) that handles authorization or [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl). Note: Authorization is diferent from Authentication. Let us know if it helps and fit to your needs.

Comment: @BrunoGrisoliaCasarotti Thank you for your answer. I found a solution in another question, also thank you for sharing interesting packages.

Answer (score 2):

You should use some kind of authentication like passport and a middleware could be helpful to protect your static files:

```
app.use('/admin', function(req,res,next){
 if(req.user){
   return express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
 } else {
   res.render(403, 'login', {message:'Please, login!'});
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seem like a effective and easy soultion for me. Unfortunately express.static function is not working for me inside any other funcion.