# Can Angular Universal be used as a server side Guard for routing?

Tags: angular, security, routes, server-side-rendering

Can SSR Angular Universal be used to check from the backend if a user has the proper authorisation before sending him new chunks of the app?

In particular, can we configure the Node.js Express server pipeline for that purpose? How would one do this?

If not possible using Universal, is there any way to protect lazy loaded modules? Some way that wouldn't involved guards, since they are a client-side check.
I looked at several posts regarding this issue but no one seems to have solved it.

Comment: This is what the `canLoad` guard is for

Comment: The canLoad guard is a check performed on the client side. What I wish to perform is a check on the  server side, for security reason.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613672/3106920